# Как повторно заэмитить элементы из первой последовательности если у второй вызван OnNext

Tags: android, rxjava2

При открытии приложения репозиторий возвращает `Observable`:

```
  fun role(): Observable<Triple<Role, Boolean, List<Int>>> {
    return repository
            .data()
            .map {
                val bgList = it.directions
                        .flatMap {
                            it.departments
                        }
                        .flatMap {
                            it.businessGroups
                        }

                when {
                    bgList.size > 1 -> Role.MANAGER
                    it.directions.isNotEmpty() -> Role.RBG
                    it.directions.isEmpty() -> Role.NOT_RBG

                    else -> Role.NOT_RBG
                }
            }
            .map {
                val requireBg = (it == Role.MANAGER && preferences.bgSelect.get() == null)
                Triple(it, requireBg, tabs())
            }
}
```

Но в случае изменения роли в настройках меняются данные приходящие с сервера и надо заставить вызваться эту последовательность снова.

Я создал класс:

```
class BgChange @Inject constructor() {

val change: Subject<Any> = PublishSubject.create()

fun isBgChange(): Observable<Any> = change
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку в настройках вызывается `onNext`: `bgChange.change.onNext(Any())`
Теперь, как я понял, мне нужно с помощью оператора `flatMap` добавить этот сигнал в мою последовательность чтобы при вызове `onNext` `Observable` повторно эмитил данные. Все попытки не увенчались успехом. Объясните как это можно сделать?

Comment: ох ну и чейн... вам нужно в подписке на change сделать flatMap { role() } , в момент change.onNext() стриггерится подписка и вызовется по чейну ваш role(), вы можете реализацию с role() убрать просто сделать например fun role() = repository.data() чтоб не пугать кто захочет расписать вам ответ с rxSubject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил проблему с помощью оператора switchMap:

```
.switchMap { triple ->
                bgChange.isBgChange()
                        .map {
                            triple
                        }
                        .startWith(triple)
            }
```